# WCF REST service multiple contracts with same base URI

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

I am writing a WCF Rest API to be consumed by third party clients. At the moment I have two service contracts:

1. ProductsService.svc
2. BookingService.svc

To give the services a decent looking Uri I have defined the following Route in Global.asx:

```
RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("api", new WebServiceHostFactory(),
typeof(ProductsService)));
```

and have also decorated my operation contracts in ProductsService.svc file with the following UriTemplate:

```
WebGet(UriTemplate = "products/")
```

This allows for URLs like api/products/...

I am lost at how to make the second service i.e. BookingService accessible at the following URL: api/booking. I cannot Add another Entry to the Route table that starts with "api" because it has already been added.

Got any ideas on how I should proceed on this one?

Comment: Why don't you use "api" as the vdir name, and then "products" and "booking" as the ServiceRoutes?

Comment: Appreciate your input @Cheeso. I figured i can also add "/api/products" and "/api/booking" to the routeTable.